# Shader Tutorial Doesn't Render Normals

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I am trying to learn about shaders by trying to do [this](https://roystan.net/articles/outline-shader.html) tutorial. I finished the first part where I was able to draw the outlines using depth. But even though I copied everything accordingly during the normal map phase, I only get a black screen. Is there something wrong with my following?

My outline shader looks like this, so currently I am only rendering the normals but screen is all black. I've modified other files as well according to the tutorial. Maybe there's a problem with the new version of unity? I don't know. Help would be much apperciated.

```
Shader "Hidden/Roystan/Outline Post Process"
{
    SubShader
    {
        Cull Off ZWrite Off ZTest Always

        Pass
        {
            // Custom post processing effects are written in HLSL blocks,
            // with lots of macros to aid with platform differences.
            // https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/PostProcessing/wiki/Writing-Custom-Effects#shader
            HLSLPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex VertDefault
            #pragma fragment Frag

            #include "Packages/com.unity.postprocessing/PostProcessing/Shaders/StdLib.hlsl"

            TEXTURE2D_SAMPLER2D(_MainTex, sampler_MainTex);
            // _CameraNormalsTexture contains the view space normals transformed
            // to be in the 0...1 range.
            TEXTURE2D_SAMPLER2D(_CameraNormalsTexture, sampler_CameraNormalsTexture);
            TEXTURE2D_SAMPLER2D(_CameraDepthTexture, sampler_CameraDepthTexture);
        
            // Data pertaining to _MainTex's dimensions.
            // https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-PropertiesInPrograms.html
            float4 _MainTex_TexelSize;
            float _Scale;
            float _DepthThreshold;
            float _NormalThreshold;

            // Combines the top and bottom colors using normal blending.
            // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes#Normal_blend_mode
            // This performs the same operation as Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha.
            float4 alphaBlend(float4 top, float4 bottom)
            {
                float3 color = (top.rgb * top.a) + (bottom.rgb * (1 - top.a));
                float alpha = top.a + bottom.a * (1 - top.a);

                return float4(color, alpha);
            }

            float4 Frag(VaryingsDefault i) : SV_Target
            {
                float halfScaleFloor = floor(_Scale * 0.5);
                float halfScaleCeil = ceil(_Scale * 0.5);

                float2 bottomLeftUV = i.texcoord - float2(_MainTex_TexelSize.x, _MainTex_TexelSize.y) * halfScaleFloor;
                float2 topRightUV = i.texcoord + float2(_MainTex_TexelSize.x, _MainTex_TexelSize.y) * halfScaleCeil;  
                float2 bottomRightUV = i.texcoord + float2(_MainTex_TexelSize.x * halfScaleCeil, -_MainTex_TexelSize.y * halfScaleFloor);
                float2 topLeftUV = i.texcoord + float2(-_MainTex_TexelSize.x * halfScaleFloor, _MainTex_TexelSize.y * halfScaleCeil);

                float depth0 = SAMPLE_DEPTH_TEXTURE(_CameraDepthTexture, sampler_CameraDepthTexture, bottomLeftUV).r;
                float depth1 = SAMPLE_DEPTH_TEXTURE(_CameraDepthTexture, sampler_CameraDepthTexture, topRightUV).r;
                float depth2 = SAMPLE_DEPTH_TEXTURE(_CameraDepthTexture, sampler_CameraDepthTexture, bottomRightUV).r;
                float depth3 = SAMPLE_DEPTH_TEXTURE(_CameraDepthTexture, sampler_CameraDepthTexture, topLeftUV).r;

                float3 normal0 = SAMPLE_TEXTURE2D(_CameraNormalsTexture, sampler_CameraNormalsTexture, bottomLeftUV).rgb;
                float3 normal1 = SAMPLE_TEXTURE2D(_CameraNormalsTexture, sampler_CameraNormalsTexture, topRightUV).rgb;
                float3 normal2 = SAMPLE_TEXTURE2D(_CameraNormalsTexture, sampler_CameraNormalsTexture, bottomRightUV).rgb;
                float3 normal3 = SAMPLE_TEXTURE2D(_CameraNormalsTexture, sampler_CameraNormalsTexture, topLeftUV).rgb;

                float3 normalFiniteDifference0 = normal1 - normal0;
                float3 normalFiniteDifference1 = normal3 - normal2;

                float edgeNormal = sqrt(dot(normalFiniteDifference0, normalFiniteDifference0) + dot(normalFiniteDifference1, normalFiniteDifference1));
                edgeNormal = edgeNormal > _NormalThreshold ? 1 : 0;

                return edgeNormal;

                float depthFiniteDifference0 = depth1 - depth0;
                float depthFiniteDifference1 = depth3 - depth2;

                float edgeDepth = sqrt(pow(depthFiniteDifference0, 2) + pow(depthFiniteDifference1, 2)) * 100;
                edgeDepth = edgeDepth > _DepthThreshold ? 1 : 0;

            

                float edge = max(edgeDepth, edgeNormal);
                //return edge;
            }
            ENDHLSL
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just after the HLSLPROGRAM you have two #pragma, one for the vertex method and one for the fragment method, but later in the code, you only have the fragment function (Frag) and the vertex one is missing (VertDefault). As far as I know, you must have both methods implemented in a fragment shader in order for it to properly work. Hope I helped.